# Law of implication. What is $p \rightarrow \neg q$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

According to law of implication, if $p\rightarrow q \iff \neg p\lor q$. What is $p\rightarrow \neg q$?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some equivalent forms:
$$p\rightarrow\neg q \iff \neg p\lor \neg  q \\
\iff \neg (p\land q) \\
\iff q \rightarrow\neg p $$